# Custom converter with attributes JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I want a really simple thing. Just create my own converter and supply some attributes. I am aware of `<f:attribute>` but it get's ugly so I want real attributes... I also want auto-complete in Eclipse to work etc.

I started with a taglib, added my converter there exactly like they do it in Omnifaces and Created my converter with `@FacesConverter`

However I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.bogus.myConverter must be an instance of javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:489)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.FaceletsCompilerSupport.loadLibraries(FaceletsCompilerSupport.java:157)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.loadLibraries(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2520)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createCompiler(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2166)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.initialize(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2458)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:133)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.checkResourceExists(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:587)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.handleSuffixMapping(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:507)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.calculateViewId(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerImpl.java:122)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.execute(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:89)
    at javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.execute(LifecycleWrapper.java:46)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:130)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:115)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.sirona.web.servlet.SironaFilter$Invocation.proceed(SironaFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.sirona.web.servlet.SironaFilter.proceed(SironaFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.sirona.web.servlet.SironaFilter.proceed(SironaFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.sirona.aop.AbstractPerformanceInterceptor.doInvoke(AbstractPerformanceInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.sirona.web.servlet.SironaFilter.doFilter(SironaFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Implementing `TagHandler` feels wrong and does not work anyways because the Converter is not called. I did register my taglib with `facelets.LIBRARIES` in `web.xml` and my taglib is really simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://mynamespace/</namespace>
    <tag>

        <tag-name>org.bogus.myConverter</tag-name>
        <converter>
            <converter-id>org.bogus.myConverter</converter-id>
            <handler-class>org.bogus.MyConverter</handler-class>
        </converter>
        <attribute>
            <name>asd</name>
            <name>bb</name>
            <name>cc</name>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

EDIT:

this source code change in omnifaces was needed to get `o:converter` to work like proposed. Obviously I can't keep this workaround in my project :/ but the converter can be wrapped by myfaces or deltaspike see `ConverterWrapper` in myfaces source for example:

```
RenderTimeTagHandlerHelper.java

try {
    Class clazz = null;
    T wrappedInstance = null;
    for (PropertyDescriptor property : Introspector.getBeanInfo(instance.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (property.getName().equals("wrapped")) {
            wrappedInstance = (T) property.getReadMethod().invoke(instance);
            clazz = wrappedInstance.getClass();
        }
    }
    if (clazz == null) {
        clazz = instance.getClass();
    }
    else {
        instance = wrappedInstance;
    }
    for (PropertyDescriptor property : Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        Method setter = property.getWriteMethod();
```

Comment: Not as pretty but better then anything I have now :)

You think this is a bug in myfaces?

Comment: @BalusC Can you create a real answer if this is the best you can think of? so I can mark it as accepted... This is fine actually - but if you have any more info the web needs to know :)

Comment: Ok well the problem with this method is that my instance is wrapped by deltaspike or myfaces so when omnifaces introspects it to find the properties it reads it from the wrapper not the real instance.

Same problem if you have 


 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CDI_MANAGED_CONVERTERS_ENABLED</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CDI_MANAGED_VALIDATORS_ENABLED</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: @BalusC your method had a problem see edit

Comment: @BalusC well the construcor get's called but never the converter methods If I make it a tagHandler :/

No change to make omnifaces accept the wrapper thing? It's there to stay in myfaces I think and many people like Deltaspike as well